# ASP.NET MVC Проблема с вызовом и обновлением частичного представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть asp.net mvc сайт. Суть сайта, передача и оплата показаний услуг организации.
Есть 2 параметра, пользователь может либо ввести свои текущие показания, при этом страница должна отобразить сумму к оплате с учетом пересчета показаний либо пользователь может ввести свою сумму, но при этом сайт должен пересчитать текущие показания.
Решил реализовать через частичное представление ввод показаний.
[image: сайт]
При запуске в дебаге VS IIS Express проблем нет, но при переносе сайта на локальный IIS - проблема. См.скрин. До раздела с текущими показаниями отображается основная View, после Частичное. Не могу понять почему появляется 500 ошибка?
В основном View

```
<div id="container">
        @Html.Partial("PartialViewsS", new Test.Models.PartViewModel());
    </div>
```

Частичное представление:

```
@model Test.Models.PartViewModel    
div id="detailsDiv">
    <table class="table" style="width:455px;word-wrap:break-word">
        <tr id="result_tr">
            <th align="left">Текущие показания</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="ss" id="curpokaz" name="curpokaz" style="height:40px" value="@Model.Pok" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">К оплате,руб</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" style="height:40px" id="sumkoplate" name="sumkoplate"  value="@Model.Opl" />
            </td>
            <td hidden>
                <input type="text" id="koplate" name="koplate" value="@Model.Opl" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:limegreen">
            <th align="left">Комиссия за платеж,руб</th>
            <td>
                <div id="komis">@Model.Kom</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Итого к оплате (с учетом комиссии),руб</th>
            <td>
                @Model.Itog
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>   

    <div class="_parent">
        <div class="box">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" disabled type="submit" id="BtnBy" name="BtnBy" style="width:200px; height:50px;border-radius:15px">ОПЛАТИТЬ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    window.onload = function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("PartialViewsS")',
            data: {
                "ls": document.getElementById('lsid').value,
                "pok": 0,
                "sopl":0,
                "i": 0
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#container').html(data);
             }            
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#curpokaz").blur(function () {            
            if (parseFloat(document.getElementById('curpokaz').value) > parseFloat(document.getElementById('pok').value)) {                
                        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '';
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("PartialViewsS")',
                            data: {
                                "ls": document.getElementById('lsid').value,
                                "pok": parseFloat(document.getElementById('curpokaz').value),
                                "sopl":0,
                                "i": 1
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#container').html(data);
                            }
                        });
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Внимание! Введите правильное значение с счетчика.";
             }
        });       


    });   
</script>
```

В контроллере идет анализ,наполнение PartViewModel и возврат.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialViewsS(string ls, double? pok, double? sopl,int i)
{

}
```

В основном View и частичном разные модели. 
Наверно что-то не правильно сделал, но не могу понять что именно.

---

Вопрос решен. Как оказалось проблема была в контроллере. (банальное преобразование типов).

Comment: Внешне всё выглядит правильно. Пробовали залогировать параметры при входе в PartialViewsS?

Comment: Да конечно. Ставил на входе в метод, все параметры передаются. В бд я их увидел. часть JS ($("#curpokaz").blur(function () { ) отрабатывает, в ajax добавил  error: function () {alert('Error');}, выбрасывает error. + то что в консоле разработчика браузера. Может я уже думал это из-за некорректного вызова PartViewModel в  @Html.Partial("PartialViewsS", new Test.Models.PartViewModel());